# SHELL environment variable keeps returning the value of default shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm using a terminal emulator with bash as the default shell ,then printed the value of the environment variable SHELL to print the current shell and it did , but when i enter another shell i.e., zshell , it keep returning the first value of the default one .

How to get it to print out the value of the current shell i'm residing at ?

```
$ echo $SHELL 
/bin/bash

$ zsh 
unixnode% 

$ unixnode% echo $SHELL 
/bin/bash
```

Comment: That's what SHELL is, it's your login shell. Unless you set it in your dotfiles, SHELL does not change when you launch a new shell

Comment: @glennjackman can you please elaborate further more . i read about multiple ways by which i can get to know about the current shell , but printing the value of the SHELL variable was the one that didn't work out i.e, the value kept persistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're logged in with a login-in shell , the shell variable gets assigned to that shell .

Whenever you used a non-login shell such as like simply running the zsh from within the current login shell session , the value of the variable Shell will remain the same , yet if you want to have it changed to the other shell then you'll have to log-out and login back again into the other shell .

Answer (score 0):

> How to get to print out the value of the current shell i'm residing at

It depends on the shell. For POSIX-type shells, use `$0`

```bsh
$ bash -c 'echo $SHELL; echo $0'
/usr/local/bin/fish
bash

$ /bin/bash -c 'echo $SHELL; echo $0'
/usr/local/bin/fish
/bin/bash

$ zsh -c 'echo $SHELL; echo $0'
/usr/local/bin/fish
zsh

$ ksh  -c 'echo $SHELL; echo $0'
/usr/local/bin/fish
ksh

$ dash  -c 'echo $SHELL; echo $0'
/usr/local/bin/fish
dash
```

---

The bash manual has [this to say about $SHELL](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SHELL)

Some more interesting things about how different shells *initialize* $SHELL

```bsh
$ unset SHELL; bash -c 'echo $SHELL'
/usr/local/bin/fish

$ unset SHELL; ksh -c 'echo $SHELL'
/bin/sh

$ unset SHELL; zsh -c 'echo $SHELL'


$ unset SHELL; dash -c 'echo $SHELL'


$ unset SHELL; fish -c 'echo $SHELL'


$ unset SHELL; tcsh -c 'echo $SHELL'
SHELL: Undefined variable.
```